# Intersection point of a tangent of a circle with a line

Tags: trigonometry

So, I'm studying math (for school) and I'm having some trouble in this one below:

01.13 - In the Picture below, the **s** line crosses the **P** dot and by the center of the circle of **R** radius, intersecting by the **Q** dot, between **P** and the center.
Besides, the **t** line crosses by **P**, it's tangent by the circle and creates an **α** angle with the line **s**. If PQ = 2R, so the **α** cosine iquals:

[image]

The answer is:

$$
\frac{ {2}{\sqrt{2}}} {3}
$$

How can I get there?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Join the centre (C) and the tangent point (Y).

The distance $PC = PQ + QC = 2r + r = 3r$

The distance from Y to C is r

Thus,

\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha) &= \dfrac{r}{3r} \\
&=\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\cos(\alpha) &= \sqrt{(1-\sin^2(\alpha)}\\
&=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{9}}\\
&=\dfrac{2\sqrt 2}{3}
\end{align}

EDIT : Since you were not aware of $$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$$

\begin{align}
\cos(\alpha)&=\dfrac{PY}{PC}\\
\text {By Pythagoras Theorem,}\\
PC^2&=PY^2+CY^2\\
(3r)^2&=PY^2+r^2\\
PY^2&=8r^2\\
\implies \cos(\alpha)&=\dfrac{2\sqrt 2 r}{3r}\\
\cos(\alpha)&=\dfrac{2\sqrt 2}{3}\\
\end{align}
We apply pythagoras because the tangent is perpendicular to the radius at the point of contact. That's a theorem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm reading your answer a couple of times to understand it, as english isn't my first language I didn't understand it by the first time. thank you so much for the quick answer!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto. My pleasure. Let me know if you need clarification on any step.

Comment: I just didn't understand yet how you transformed the sin into a cos, is it a regulation (I don't know if it's the right word)? Thanks again.

Comment: Do you know the pythagorean identity $sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2 = 1$ ?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. Thank you so much for that info.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto. I added another way of doing it which doesn't need that result.

Comment: However the Sin(α) shouldn't be opposite/hypotenuse? In this case r/YP? looks like you used the opposite/adjacent, in that case shouldn't we use Tangent?
Thank you so much and sorry for bothering you so much.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto. See figure in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, I was going crazy yesterday...
I had understand something quite different: http://picbox.im/image/a2ccbaa95d-matematica1b01_132.jpg
I have no words to thank you, I've never heard before of sin(x)2+cos(x)2=1.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, but just for increase my knowledge, how are you sure that the tangent point and the center line creates a 90° angle with the Tangent? Thank you so much.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto. It's a theorem. It actually follows from the definition of a tangent.

Comment: Interesting... Thank you so much for sharing this!